# which is better performance to display many marker maps v2 android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have more than 10.000 markers in google maps v2 I took away from the my server, I have a problem to bring it up to show on maps, I have two techniques to it.

1. I took all the data marker at a time and display on maps
2. I take a piece of data markers based to the position that I see on the map, for example: when a user directs his map to another position,the closest marker will be display from server.

I use the first method,the result is a map stopped (freeze) a few seconds, after which the marker appears,my map runs slow ..

I also use the second way, it is more than fast than the first method but will be slow when the internet connection is weak

from two ways above which is more efficient and faster or may be other ways to become my map to be better performance?
thanks..

Comment: Are you using and array or sqlite db?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Android Map Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/). Along with what @d.aemon has noted about sqlite you can use the clustering library along with adding markers dynamically based on where the user is on the map.

Quick setup for clustering and dynamic markers, if you are using Android Studio:

In build.gradle (module: app):

```
compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
```

When map is created in your code:

```
 map.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings().enabled(true)
                .addMarkersDynamically(true).minMarkersCount(5));
```

I do not have the amount of markers you do, but this library far exceeds the Google Utilities library in power. It is so much more fluid in the UI. I have tried a variety of different arrays (lists, sparse array, etc...) to handle my data, and so far it is working really well. I am sure using sqlite as proposed will be just as quick.

Initially when you add all your markers, you will need to figure out the quickest/best way to handle that in your Async task (as I am using... btw [Android Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) is a real nice library for async stuff), so check out:

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

...while do in background, but the marker clustering offered with Android Map Extensions will do the rest for you.

There are other techniques also I have seen like using a timer within an async task basically adding 100 markers at a time and then pausing your async task so the UI is still somewhat responsive.

Hope some of that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't refresh markers on the fly from the internet at first place. Try to combine both ways:

1. Download all marker data to a local database
2. Query the database each time user changes map view and update markers (this is pretty quick in SQLite)

This approach has also some cons, though:

- You can't avoid refreshing huge amount of markers when user zooms out (consider limiting the maximum amount of markers displayed or some sort of markers clustering)
- Each refresh of markers takes significant amount of time even when the amount of markers is low (my app refreshes about 400 - 500 markers in about 250 - 300 ms on Nexus 7 2012)

I'm too still struggling with this kind of problem as my application has to display about 8 thousand markers. I've found just one clustering method so far which was completely unusable, because the clustering itself took about the same time as the refresh itself, thus blocked UI thread for many seconds each time I changed zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster map extension is superb but if have not to do that much work and just wanted to load custom maker logo from URL, below solution would work for you.

```
private fun loadMarkerOnGoogleMap(barVenueList: List<VenueModel>) {
    for (row in barVenueList) {
        val frame = BitFact.decodeResource(mActivity.resources, R.drawable.pin)
        getBitmap(mActivity, row.logoImage, object : BitmapUtils.OnDownloadCallBack {
            override fun marker(bitmap: Bitmap) {
                val finalLogo = mergeToPin(frame, bitmap)
                if (row.getLatitude() != null && row.getLongitude() != null) {
                    val latLong = LatLng(row.getLatitude()!!, row.getLongitude()!!)
                    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLong)
                    markerOptions.title(row.venueName)
                    markerOptions.icon(BitDescFact.fromBitmap(finalLogo))
                    markerOptions.snippet(row.venueName)
                    val addMarker = mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    addMarker.tag = row //set tag to get data when required

                }
            }
        })
    }
}

/**
 * @param mActivity Activity,
 * @param imageURL : String image url
 * @param mCallBack : OnDownloadCallback
 */
fun getBitmap(mActivity: Activity, imageURL: String, mCallBack: OnDownloadCallBack) {
    Glide.with(mActivity)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(imageURL)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(50, 50) {
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                println("onLoadCleared ## ")
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                println("onResourceReady ## ")
                mCallBack.marker(resource)
            }
        })
}

/**
 * Interface to listen download
 */
interface OnDownloadCallBack {
    fun marker(bitmap: Bitmap)
}
```